# How to add Table of Content using HTML or other options?

Tags: articles, html

I'm looking for an answer to how to create a Table of content while publishing the article in Joomla. I know "page break" option but the default option design does not look on the blog page. I want Table of content look good as shown in other platform or Wikipedia.

**Is there any option to create TOC using HTML?**

Also, I'm not willing to use any extension for the same (I'd appreciate if you advice extension for it if there is no other option available).

Answer (score 1):

The Table Of Contents plugin can do that. Look in the Joomla Extension Directory (JED).

https://extensions.joomla.org/tags/articles-toc/